# Main disk have strange filesystem

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, ntfs

I have my data disk (hdd, 1,5TB), that I'm using in windows just fine (ntfs). When I look at it with MiniTool Partition Wizard, I get 2 partitions, both simple ntfs, with same letter. Strange, but working. However, when I use Linux gParted to look at the partition, it says unknown filesystem. Windows disk (ntfs too) is recognized just fine.

Is there a way to join these 2 partitions, so linux can recognize then as normal ntfs filesystem?

Comment: Are you sure the second partition isn't a "recovery" partition?

Comment: Can you tell us the size of second partition? 100-200MB?

Comment: It is like 900MB one partition and 600MB the other one. Windows uses it as one big 1,5TB partition